# Change item quantity on mini cart

Tags: theme, cart

I added my mini cart to the header and now I have a nice popup that shows the list of items inside my cart. I can see how many items I have of each on my cart but I want the user to be able to change that quantity. What is the best way to achieve this?

This is the part that's getting the content of the mini cart:

```
<?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>

            <div id="header-items">
                <!--div class="block-subtitle">
                    <span><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></span> 
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>-->

                <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
                <a class="view_all" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo ($_cartQty > 3) ? $this->__('View All Items'): $this->__('View Cart');?></a>                                             
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button checkout" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>                                
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>
        <div id="header-items">
            <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

And on the php file I have this (among other functions):

```
public function getRecentItems($count = null)
    {
        if ($count === null) {
            $count = $this->getItemCount();
        }

        $items = array();
        if (!$this->getSummaryCount()) {
            return $items;
        }

        $i = 0;
        $allItems = array_reverse($this->getItems());
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
            if (!$item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $products  = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/url')
                    ->getRewriteByProductStore(array($productId => $item->getStoreId()));
                if (!isset($products[$productId])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $urlDataObject = new Varien_Object($products[$productId]);
                $item->getProduct()->setUrlDataObject($urlDataObject);
            }

            $items[] = $item;
            if (++$i == $count) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

Right now this gives me this: item - qty - remove button - edit button And I want to replace the edit button with input to change the quantity of the items

Comment: Did you solve the problem already? If yes, how? If no, this blogpost from tomrobertshaw might help you: http://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/08/add-increase-and-decrease-quantity-buttons-to-items-in-magento-cart/

Comment: I have not solved this yet, but that post is to change it on the actual cart, I do have that already, I'm talking about the mini cart on the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what cart you are talking about. What you need is the URL which is called to change the qty of a product and these url is:

```
\Mage_Checkout_CartController::updatePostAction()
```

so the url is:

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost');
```

And then you just need to add the `$qouteIitem->getId()` and the new `$qty` in a form. Send the form in the format `array(cart => array($quoteItemId => $qty))` to this URL and the quantities are updated.