# Change product quantity in a cart one by one

Tags: cart, ajax

What is necessary in order to change product quantity in a cart one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: 7ochem, what's up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the post that answered to my question:

[Change item quantity on mini cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/change-item-quantity-on-mini-cart?rq=1)

Thank you Fabian Blechschmidt !